Understanding the invariance of this infinite series geometrically
Recently I worked through a computation that $L=1/4$.
I couldn't help but notice $L_{\rho}$ seems to be invariant under "re-scalings" of the the underlying arithmetic function. What I mean by that is if we consider
$$L_{\rho}= \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\int_0^{e^{-\sqrt{\rho(n)}}} \sum_{n=1}^k e^{\frac{\rho(n)}{\ln(t)}} \, dt}{\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^k e^{\frac{\rho(n)}{\ln(t)}} \, dt}=1/4$$
for an arbitrary mapping $\rho:\Bbb N \to \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ then $L_{\rho}$ seems to be invariant no matter what mapping is chosen.

Is $L_{\rho}$ indeed $1/4$ independent of what mapping $\rho(n)$ is chosen? Is there a name for this invariance or some nice geometric way of understanding it?

I'm looking for an explanation that hopefully gives a visual/geometric way of understanding this using sums of areas. I do have somewhat of a geometric story for $L_{\rho}$ but I feel like I need a different viewpoint to get the full picture.
